# Latex Dollar Sign \\ How do I signify Linux Environment Variables in latex?

Tags: linux, latex, environment-variables, dollar-sign

I am aware to output dollar signs you escape it with \ such that:

```
\$          % prints '$'
```

However, I can't print something like

```
\$ JAVA_HOME       % prints '$ JAVA_HOME'
```

The space in between the $ and JAVA_HOME is what's annoying.  How can I make it so it's one word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the space? \$JAVAHOME gives what I expect:

```
$ grep JAVA test.tex 
\$JAVAHOME

$ ps2ascii test.ps
$JAVAHOME
```

Comment: Interesting... I could've sworn that it wouldn't let me do that.  I just tested it and it does it now.